# Creating multiple Jupyter working directories/config files in Anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, config, conda

I have Anaconda Navigator on my work computer and I've changed the default working directory for Jupyter notebooks to be a certain location on the firm server, using the steps given [here](https://medium.com/@shanyitan/how-to-change-the-working-directory-of-jupyter-and-jupyter-lab-on-windows-environment-bbe5a5a99f05)

I have also created a second environment in Anaconda, for which I would like to use a different Jupyter Notebook working directory than that of the base (root). To do this, I believe I would need to:

1. Create a second Jupyter Notebook config file
2. Get the second environment to refer to the new config file, while ensuring that the old file still referred to the original config file.

How would I go about this? Alternate approaches to creating multiple working directories also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking to achieve the same result: pass different configurations which would include specific [settings such as working and workspace directories](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html) when launching Jupyter Notebook/Lab in different conda or other virtual environments.

Noticing the following:

```sh
jupyter lab --help

  --config=<Unicode>
      Full path of a config file.
      Default: ''
      Equivalent to: [--JupyterApp.config_file]
```

Thus, to achieve the desired result, it is possible to pass the path to the relevant config file upon launching Jupyter Lab/Notebook as such:

```sh
jupyter lab --config=~/.jupyter/path_to_my_custom_jupyter_config_for_env_1.py
# or
jupyter notebook --config=~/.jupyter/path_to_my_custom_jupyter_config_for_env_1.py
```

You can copy your current configuration file, make the relevant adjustments and save it as a different file. You would then pass the path to that new config file when launching Jupyter as per above. To simplify, you can create shortcuts that do that (instead of typing/copying the specific parameters on each launch).

Otherwise (with no specific argument passed), Jupyter Lab/Notebook will launch using the [default configuration file](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html) if it exists, which is always located in the home directory of the Unix user launching Jupyter (`~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`).